# Vim - wait for file syntax check before exit

Tags: macos, vim, yaml, syntastic

I am using Vim 7.4 on MacOSX with [scrooloose/syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) plugin to edit YAML files.

I have mapped F11 to:

```
:wa<CR>
```

- the file is checked for yaml validity (it uses node and js-yaml if I 
  recall correctly).
- I get an indication (not perfect) of where any
  error might be.

I have also mapped F12 to:

```
:wa<CR>:xa<CR>
```

Now to me... since F11 does a js-yaml check and reports errors, F12 should also do the same thing since the mapping is ALMOST identical.

My problem is that before js-yaml file checker can return with any errors, Vim will exit. I don't know how to have it wait for js-yaml to return.

Any suggestions?

In Vim I did a quick ":help pause" → to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to set `g:syntastic_check_on_wq` to 1 and to map your <kbd>F12</kbd> to `:wqa<CR>`.

The more complicated (but smoother) solution involves writing the buffers, then checking all of them for syntastic errors.  You'll need some VimL-fu for that though.

Also, please note that syntastic doesn't work very well when checking several files at the same time (which you do when you run `:wa`).  This is related to limitations in Vim API.